# What does 'Invalid module format' mean?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, kernel-modules, modprobe

After executing...

```
sudo modprobe rt3572sta
```

I get...

> Invalid module format

What does it mean? I'm trying to get Wusb600n v2 working on Lucid Lynx.

Does it mean that kernel versions aren't compatible?

Comment: What do `uname -a` and `file /path/to/rt3572sta.ko` show? Where did you get the rt3572sta module from?

Comment: You can take a look [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x380.html) to understand it better. The link explains why this error occurs and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the file you are trying to load is not a valid kernel module.  Either it never was, or it has been corrupted, or possibly it is for an architecture other than the one you have ( 32 vs 64 bit ).